# Float right without creating new line

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div>Due date:<input type="text" name="dueDate" size="30" value="{{ticket.fields.interval.lastExecution|e}}" required  disabled="disabled"></input></div>
<div>Created by:<input type="text" name="createdBy" size="30" value="{{ticket.fields.personCreated|e}}" required  disabled="disabled"></input></div>
```

CSS:

```
.open-tickets-view input {
    border:         0px solid #474a52;
    border-radius:  0px;
    max-width:      200px;
```

RESULT:
[image]

If I try to float right with inline-block display:

CSS:

```
.open-tickets-view input {
    border:         0px solid #474a52;
    border-radius:  0px;
    max-width:      200px;
    display:        inline-block;
    float:          right;
```

RESULT:
[image]

I have tried several different combinations among `display: flex` and `use justify-content: space-between` but the text always breaks a new line.

Comment: share complete css  and html  or make live demo ?

Comment: The `<input>` element is self closing. `</input>` does not exist.

Comment: @caramba, thanks. I have modified it. However, sadly didn't change the result.

Comment: please share complete html and css you are using ?

Comment: Set width:100% to your holder div and next set float to right elements.  consider div with display table or flex boxes are the right ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With input elements it's a good thing to use `<label>`. Cause it's a label for the input. Default browser behavior with labels is that if you click on the label the mouse will focus the input. [Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)

Using float:

```css
div.myDiv {
   width: 300px;
   border: solid 2px red;
}
div.myDiv:after {
   /* clear floats is a good thing */
   content: '';
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
div.myDiv input {
   float: right;
   border:solid 2px green;
}
div.myDiv label {
   border:solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <label for="uname">Choose a username: </label>
  <input type="text" id="uname" name="name">
</div>
```

using positioning:

```css
div.myDiv {
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   border: solid 2px red;
}
div.myDiv input {
   border:solid 2px green;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
div.myDiv label {
   border:solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <label for="uname">Choose a username: </label>
  <input type="text" id="uname" name="name">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I am testing it now

Comment: I changed position: absolute into left: 115 and it works perfectly even when I shrink the screen size! Thanks

Comment: @Mykita if you change `div.myDiv { width: 100%; }` then it would also work with ´right: 0;´ and shrinking. Either way, glad it helped, happy coding

Answer (score 3):

You can use `margin-left:auto` on a child element of `display:flex` with `flex-direction:row` like below.

```css
.container, .container > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.container .right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    <span>Due date:</span>
    <input type="text" name="dueDate" size="30" value="{{ticket.fields.interval.lastExecution|e}}" required disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <span>Created by:</span><input type="text" name="createdBy" size="30" value="{{ticket.fields.personCreated|e}}" required disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or maybe:

```css
.container,
.container>div {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container>div {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding:1em;
}

.container .right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    <span>Due date:</span>
    <input class='right' type="text" name="dueDate" size="30" value="{{ticket.fields.interval.lastExecution|e}}" required disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Created by:</span><input class='right' type="text" name="createdBy" size="30" value="{{ticket.fields.personCreated|e}}" required disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: given css in question is working , problem in another css or html code

Comment: Thanks I am testing it now!

Comment: The second code snippet was the closest. However, the text ended up in the middle of the screen (had to scroll in the container). Thanks anyway a bunch!